# Hide/remove Option set value using JavaScript for CRM Dynamics 365?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

working on a tutorial at home with Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM, to hide a Option Set Value from  a dropdown, however this dropdown also is used on a Business Process Flow, I dont want to delete the Option Set Value, just hide it i.e. removeopotion/hide.

Im trying to use JavaScript to hide/remove this, however Im very new to JS and dont really understand it, my code is below:

```
function hideOptions(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    
    if (formContext.ui.getFormType() == 1 || formContext.ui.getFormType() == 2 ) {
        var pickList = formContext.Page.getControl("statuscode");
        pickList.removeOption("Test1");
        pickList.removeOption("Test2");
        pickList.removeOption("Test3");
        pickList.removeOption("Test4");
    }
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

You should provide the numeric value in the `removeOption` method.
As it's said in microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/controls/removeoption)

> formContext.getControl(arg).removeOption(value);
> value - Number - The
> value of the option you want to remove.

Comment: can you please modify my code please dont really understand whats arg?

Comment: for example if the "Test1" value code is 100001, then write it this way: `formContext.getControl("statuscode").removeOption(100001);`

Comment: like this @Arsen? i have added answer

Comment: No, you need to provide number, not string, so you need to remove quotes as well. `pickList.removeOption(1);` and `pickList.removeOption(2);`

Comment: Edited answer I also changed line var pickList = formContext.Page.getControl("statuscode");

Comment: the error I get is Cannot read property 'removeOption' of null

Comment: Check if your `statuscode` optionset field is placed on the form. Also check the schema name of the field. If the field is placed in the header, then the schema name is `header_statuscode`

Comment: What about in the business process flow? @arsen

Comment: Cannot read property 'removeOption' of null

Comment: Hi @Arsen how did you know to put header in front? that worked, what about another one if you have a field just on the business process flow stage? my fields schema name is "new_resolutiontype" but its on the business process flow only, will header go in the front of this to? how did you know to put header in the front of the other statuscode field?

Comment: When customizing the form you have 3 parts of the form, where you can add a field. Its *header*, *body* and *footer*. If you've added field to the header it's schema name will be `header_schemaname`, in footer - `footer_schemaname`, in body - `schemaname`. In your case the field was added to the header. Asking to the second question, as I know, business process flows have nothing to do with field schema names.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this now thank you guys, was missing the correct schema name name `"header_statuscode"`

```
function hideOptions(executionContext) {

var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

 if (formContext.ui.getFormType() == 1 || formContext.ui.getFormType() == 2 ) {
 
 var pickList = formContext.getControl("header_statuscode");
 pickList.removeOption(1);
 pickList.removeOption(2);

 }
}
```